# TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() while iterating through a list

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, iteration

I get the following error 'TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()' for the program below. Why can't I iterate through a list and compare it to another list?

```
word_list = list() 

while True: 
    file_name = raw_input('Enter file name: ')
    if len(file_name) < 1: exit() 
    try: 
        file = open(file_name)
        break

    except: 
        print 'Please enter a valid file name.'
        continue

for line in file: 
    line = line.rstrip() 
    words = line.split()
    for word in words: 
        if len(word_list) <1:
            word_list = word_list.append(word)

        else: 
            if not word in word_list:
                word_list = word_list.append(word) 

word_list = word_list.sort() 
print word_list
```

Comment: Briefly: `append()` mutates the object in place and returns `None`. Don't save the result of an `append()` operation back to the same reference. Just do the operation, `word_list.append(word)`.

Answer (score 1):

[`list.append`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) returns `None`.

The following line:

```
word_list = word_list.append(word)
```

should be replaced with:

```
word_list.append(word)
```

Otherwise, `word_list` becomes `None` causing the `TypeError` later.